# How to format a simple PHP array of strings?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple function which I pass in an array of strings:

```
function myfunction( $arg = array() )
{
    // do stuff to $arg...
    // return a $string;
}
```

Simple so far, but I need some of the strings in the `$arg` array to be **formatted**, while some remain **unformatted**. I can't figure out how to do it?

Say I run this `$arg` through `myfunction()`:

```
echo myfunction( array( 'format me!', 'do not format me!' ) );
```

My tiny little brain can't figure out how to tell `myfunction()` that the first value in `$arg` array needs to have formatting, and it should not format the second value.

I thought about an associative array, but I think that could be the wrong approach because of having identical indexes.

```
echo myfunction( array( 'format' => 'hi', 'format' => 'bye', 'noformat' => 'foo');
```

Just looking for a "nudge" in the right direction.

**EDIT 1:**

Forgot to mention, I can only have **one** `$arg` array because I need the keys to be in a specific order.

**EDIT 2:**

The `$arg` array can have as many keys as the user wants.

Comment: Will there only ever be two items in the array, with the first being the only one which needs "formatting": i.e., how do *you* know which item needs formatting and which does not?

Comment: No, there can be as many items in the `$arg` array as the user wants. As to your second question, that IS the problem. =)

Comment: Is there anything about the data in the array that determines if it needs to be formatted?  How can you tell which elements get formatting if there are 100 elements?

Comment: Mark, that is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Jeff, I don't think we can answer that question with the information we have :)  Can you give us any more details?  What's the goal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
function myfunction(array $format, array $noformat) {
  ... 
}
```

or

```
function myfunction(array $strings) {
  foreach ($strings['format'] as $format) {
    // do stuff
  }
  foreach ($strings['noformat'] as $noformat) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

with:

```
myfunction(array(
  'format' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
  'noformat' => array('four', 'five', 'six'),
));
```

*If* (and only if) the strings are *unique* you can put them in the key instead of the value:

```
$strings = array(
  'one' => true,
  'two' => false,
  'three' => false,
  'four' => true,
);

myfunction($strings);
```

with:

```
function myfunction(array $strings) {
  foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
    if ($v) {
      // format string
    }
  }
}
```

But since you can't have duplicate keys this method falls down if you have repeated strings.

Comment: That is a good answer, but I forgot to mention that I need the `$args` to be in a specific order, so I cannot do a separate `$format` and a `$noformat`.

Comment: you could use e.g. array(array('format' => 'text'), array('noformat' => 'more text')) as $arg and change the myfunction to accept this as argument (the hint would be foreach ($arg as $formatKey => $text))

Comment: The "if (and only if)..." edit looks good! I think I'll give that a whirl. =)

Comment: Maybe this should be a new question, but how do you test an array to make sure all keys are unique?

Comment: All keys are unique by definition. If you try and insert the same key it overwrites the old value.

Comment: The solution for me was to use the key as my string and set whether or not formatting should be performed as (bool) in the element's value. Works perfectly, and I'm not worried about duplicate key names as I am in control of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `myfunction()` take an array as an argument, why not just have it take a single element as the argument.  Then you can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to process each element of the array.

Sort of like this:

```
function myfunction($element) {
  if( do-formatting) {
    //do your formatting stuff
    $element = formatted-stuff
  }

  return $element
}

$arr = array("format me", "don't format me");

//This calls myfunction on each element of the array
//A new array is returned where each element has been replaced
//by the return value from myfunction.  
$arr = array_map('myfunction', $arr);
```

Comment: You've just moved the question; now, how do you tell the function whether to format each individual $element?

Comment: I guess that depends on if the array only ever has 2 elements.  That wasn't clear to me from the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would to it.
The implementation of __tostring is not mandatory but is syntax sugar inside the myFunction.

```
<?php
class MyString{
    private $_value;
    public $to_format;

    public function __construct($str, $to_format = true){
        $this->_value = $str;
        $this->to_format = $to_format;
    }

    public function __tostring(){
        return $this->_value;
    }
}

$args = array( new MyString('format me'), new MyString('Not me!', false) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is oddly similar to how table rows are formatted (with a different formatting function for each row). I would provide the data as a single array, then provide formatting information as a second array based on keys. For instance:

```
function rowFormatter(Array $data, Array $format=array()) {
  ob_start();
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($format[$key])) 
      echo call_user_func($format[$key],$value);
    else 
      echo $value;
  }
  return ob_get_clean();
}

function makeBold($x) { return '<b>'.$x.'</b>'; }

rowFormatter(array( "Hello", "Mister" ), array( 0 => 'makeBold' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what these strings you are formatting actually represent, so I used generic naming on these classes:

```
class LineItem
{
    var $value;

    function __construct($val)
    {
        $this->value = $val;
    }

    function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    function getFormatted( $formatter )
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

class FormattedLineItem extends LineItem
{
    function getFormatted( $formatter )
    {
        return $formatter( $this->value );
    }
}

function myfunction( $arr=array() )
{
    $fnFormat = function($str) {
        return ucwords($str);
    };

    foreach($arr as $obj)
    {
        $str = $obj->getFormatted($fnFormat);
        echo "$str\n";
    }
}

$arr = array(
    new FormattedLineItem('format me!'),
    new LineItem('do not format me!')
);

myfunction($arr);
```

The idea is to use separate classes to distinguish between strings.